# Automatically jump to next input and submit on last one ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have 4 inputs that will act as a verification code and I would like that when the user inputs 1, it goes automatically to the next one, etc and when it reaches the last one it submits automatically. I would also like that they convert to * as it moves to the following input. Is this possible? Here is my code with the inputs.

` 

<Input
disableUnderline
inputProps={{min: 0, maxLength: 1,  style: { textAlign: 'center' }}}
type="text"
name="cod1"

```
          sx={{width:20, borderBottom:1}}/>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
      <Input
        disableUnderline
        inputProps={{min: 0, maxLength: 1, style: { textAlign: 'center' }}} 
        type="text"
        name="cod2"
      
        sx={{width:20, borderBottom:1}} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3} >
      <Input
        disableUnderline
        inputProps={{min: 0, maxLength: 1, style: { textAlign: 'center' }}} 
        type="text"
        name="cod3"
     
        sx={{width:20, borderBottom:1}} />
      </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
    <Input
      disableUnderline
      inputProps={{min: 0, maxLength: 1, style: { textAlign: 'center' }}} 
      type="text"
      name="cod4"
     
      sx={{width:20, borderBottom:1}}/>
      </Grid>`
```

I've tried using focus() but no success. I also tried react-otp-input npm but also no success. I think what I'm having trouble is with the referencing of each input. Thank you!!

Comment: Where does the `Input` component come from?

Comment: I am using Material UI, so it's imported from there